# new operator returning null - C#

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public ObjectModel.Path GetPath(int pathid)
{
    var path = this.DbContext.Paths.Find(pathid);
    var app = GetApplicationById(path.ApplicationId.GetValueOrDefault());

    var p = new Path 
    {
        ApplicationId = path.ApplicationId,
        Id = path.Id, Password = path.Password,
        UserName = path.UserName,
        LocalUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(path.LocalUrl) ? null : System.IO.Path.Combine(path.LocalUrl, app.Name)

    };


    return p;
}
```

The variable `p` is always `null`. How is this posible?

Here is a print screen of what I am talking about:

[image]

I also try with immediate windows I got this:

[image]

`p` CANNOT BE NULL since im creating a new instance of it while all of its properties are not null. I tried clean the project, restart windows, open visual studio as administrator and nothing happened.

Any idea why?

The application is running on .net 4.0, visual studio 2017 v15.2(26430.13) relase.

Comment: It's probably just your debugger. Are you debugging with optimization on (ie. release mode)? To test the theory just add a null check and throw a new `ArgumentNullException`, if you get the exception while debugging then it is null (*which I doubt because it should not be possible*) and if not then it's your debugger.

Comment: @Igor No, im in the debug mode.

Comment: Does the `Path` class override `ToString`, or is it decorated with any attributes with a name starting with "Debugger"?

Comment: What about code weaving? Are you using Microsoft Code Contracts or something similar (AOP at compile time)? That can cause the debugger to show incorrect information.

Comment: @Amy That was the problem. I am indeed overriding `ToString()` and the variable `Uri` is null.

Comment: @EinerSantana fantastic!  The debugger (by default, this can be overridden) calls `ToString` when rendering an object in a debugger view.  See the `DebuggerDisplayAttribute`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your variable is not null.

Debugger by default try to display content of ToString() method when it's overloaded. In this case it's displaying (propably) Uri or FtpUrl value which is null.

Try to click little triangle on your variable when you hover it then you will see full contents of the variable.

Comment: Nice answer, but one quibble: the debugger calls `ToString()` regardless of whether it is overridden, *unless* the `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` is specified on the type.